# Derby Database Boot Password Visible in exception text

Tags: java, eclipselink, derby

when try to connect to database with wrong database name then exception generated contain the boot password that can hacker show it easily.
how to hide boot password from exception text
**the exception**

`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database data/ClinicDatabaseQQQQ;bootPassword=DataPassword was not found.
Error Code: 40000
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database data/ClinicDatabaseQQQQ;bootPassword=DataPassword was not found.
Error Code: 40000
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: The connection was refused because the database data/ClinicDatabaseQQQQ;bootPassword=DataPassword was not found.
    ... 21 more
Caused by: ERROR 08004: The connection was refused because the database data/ClinicDatabaseQQQQ;bootPassword=DataPassword was not found.
    ... 25 more`

Comment: Could you post the JDBC URL you are using? I suspect the password is part of it and EclipseLink just prints the URL for information purpose assuming it does not contain any sensitive information.

Comment: yes , boot password in URL `jdbc:derby://192.168.1.6/data/ClinicDatabaseQQQ;user=user;password=pass;bootPassword=DataPassword'

Comment: i am using eclipse link , can i pass boot password as a jdbc property

Comment: i'm passed it in jdbc property bu it still visible in exception properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.property.bootPassword", "DataPassword");

Comment: This exception is only showing the password back to **you**. **You** are the one who entered that password. I'm not sure I'm following how the hacker is seeing your password, unless they are in the same room with you and looking over your shoulder? In which case, didn't they already see what you typed?

Comment: Are you sure you modified the URL? Can you use a JPA 2 standard property, does it make a difference? Can you use a DataSource instead of configuring EclipseLink to manage database connectivity?